# Windows 10 took long time to resolve host names

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hosts-file, ipv4, hostname

The problem I've encountered happens since 1809 update. This is some of the description of what happened:

1. My Windows laptop can connect to Wi-Fi networks. When I connect to it, this happens:
2. The system can't resolve host names (or just resolve it too long). I can `ping` to IP addresses, but can't `ping` to host names.
3. This happens with **both** internal and USB Wi-Fi adapter. Never tried on ethernet and can't use it regardless (I don't have cabled network)
4. It took 1 - 5 minutes for system to able to resolve host names.
5. I modified my `hosts` file to one that I can block malicious host names to load, which is about 1MB in size.
6. For this instance, I used Google's DNS (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) to resolve host names. I can't use IPv6 though.

Output of `ipconfig /all`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-36EQ4IS
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Unknown adapter VPN5 - VPN Client:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VPN Client Adapter - VPN5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5E-FB-EB-51-2B-C1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-B0-34-04-A6-F0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-13
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64dd:c17e:4103:819d%19(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.129.157(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 789184551
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-E4-3B-A0-40-B0-34-04-A6-F0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter USB Adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 7C-8B-CA-08-14-CE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-FB-84-97-98-80
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5A-FB-84-97-98-7F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter PC Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-FB-84-97-98-7F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.77(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Rabu, 20 Maret 2019 19.33.26
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Rabu, 20 Maret 2019 22.25.09
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 64.6.64.6
                                       64.6.65.6
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-FB-84-97-98-83
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

What should I do, while retaining my `hosts` file so my system can resolve host names quickly?

Comment: Can you check via `ipconfig /all` what nameservers are _active_? You say you can't use IPv6, but it's possible that the system somehow has IPv6 nameservers configured _anyway_ (possibly from your router via the recently-added IPv6 RDNSS support in 1809).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening due to the size of the Hosts file. If you have too many hostnames in the host file, it'll take a very long time to resolve. Not only that, you might not be able to edit it or remove hostnames from it (since it's running in the background trying to resolve).
From experience, I know that by adding many hostnames, it'll slow the internet speed.

However, there are a few things you can do to Optimize the hosts file.

- Delete comments.
- Delete Duplicates.
- Include multiple hostnames per line if they point to the same IP address. (Windows allows nine aliases per line)

You can do all of this easily by using a tool like [HostsMan](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman/)
<sup>(Alternative download links: [Link 01](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/HostsMan.shtml), [Link 02](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/HostsMan-Portable.shtml))</sup>

Size of the HOSTS file
(Hosts file located in `system32/drivers/etc/` of the Windows folder )

[image: Screenshot: Size of the HOSTS file]

Comments and hostnames

[image: Screenshot: Comments and hostnames]

After deleting comments and including hostnames per line (ex: 9)

[image: Screenshot: Delete comments & include multiple hostnames per line]

Size of the HOSTS file after deleting comments & including multiple hostnames per line
(This is without deleting any hostname)

[image: Screenshot: HOSTS file size]

Screenshot of the HostsMan Software

[image: Screenshot of the HostsMan Software]

Comment: Link is 404, found the backup from `archive.org`

Comment: @AryoAdhi, try refreshing few times. It works but I have to refresh a few times. If not, try [this link](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/HostsMan.shtml) or [this one](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/HostsMan-Portable.shtml).

Comment: Downloaded the program. It doesn't work on me with error code 2. But indeed, it's right that the size slows down my PC in resolving host names. (doesn't happen in Linux)

Comment: When hosts file is being used, you're getting that error. Try exiting any programs that use hosts file (Ex: TinyWall, ZoneAlarm). This also happens when DNS being resolved.

Comment: I never used any program which uses `hosts` file. Never heard about that too.

Comment: **Backup the hosts file**. Then delete it. Restore the backup. Run the program. (Don't try to connect to the Internet). If you cannot delete the hosts file, you might have to start [Windows in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91306/discussion-between-d-t-and-aryo-adhi).